# Passing a value to a previous view controller doesn't reflect the change

Tags: ios, swift

I have `MainViewController` and `DetailViewController` that are stacked together by a navigation controller. I want to pass a value from `DetailViewController` back to the previous controller, which is `MainViewController`.

First, I tried it with `UINavigationControllerDelegate`:

```swift
class DetailViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.delegate = self
    }
    
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        (viewController as? MainViewController)?.myClass = myClass
    }
}
```

which was to be called as `DetailViewController` is popped:

```swift
_ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

But, the new value doesn't get reflected on `MainViewController`:

```swift
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    var myClass: MyClass
    private lazy var commentLabel: UILabel = {
        let comment = UILabel()
        comment.text = myClass.comment
        comment.numberOfLines = 0
        return comment
    }()
}
```

even though when I log `myClass` in `MainViewController`, I can see that it's being passed properly.

I also tried it with a property observer so that `DetailViewController` can pass it to a temporary property observer instead:

```swift
var temp: MyClass? {
    willSet(newValue) {
        myClass = newValue
    }
}
```

but, the view controller's interface still doesn't change.

Finally, I tried creating a delegate in `MainViewController`:

```swift
protocol CallBackDelegate {
    func callBack(value: MyClass)
}
```

where the function simply passes the argument:

```swift
func callBack(value: MyClass) {
    myClass = value
}
```

I set the delegate to `self`:

```swift
if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Detail") as? DetailViewController {
    vc.delegate = self
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

and invoking the function in `DetailViewController`:

```swift
delegate?.callBack(value: MyClass)
```

but, still doesn't update the interface.  It seems as though passing the value isn't the issue, but having it be reflected is.

Comment: Simply create a property in the detail view controller of type `MainViewController` (maybe call it `mainViewControllerDelegate`, or something) and have the main view controller assign itself as the value of that property before pushing to the detail view controller. The detail view controller (that instance, anyway) now has access to all of the non-private methods in the main view controller, which could include a method to accept data from the detail view controller.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the code?

Comment: Either use a closure or protocol/delegate pattern. Trying to pass a view controller instance via navigation controller delegate is a bad idea.

Comment: I just updated my question. It seems like there is no issue passing the value between the view controllers, but I have a suspicion that something about the lazy property that's preventing the value to be loaded on the interface, but I can't pinpoint what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of using the protocol / delegate pattern. It's about as basic as it gets...

- Start a new single-view project
- add the code below
- Set the class of the default view controller to `MainViewController`
- embed it in a Navigation Controller
- run the app

Then:

- Tap the button labeled "Push to next VC"
- Enter some text in the "Edit Me" field
- Tap the "Pop back to previous VC"

See that the label has been updated with your entered text.

```
protocol CallBackDelegate: class {
    func callback(_ val: String)
}

class MainViewController: UIViewController, CallBackDelegate {

    let btn = UIButton()
    let theLabel = UILabel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        theLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(btn)
        view.addSubview(theLabel)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 100.0),
            btn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            theLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
        ])
        
        theLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        btn.backgroundColor = .red
        
        theLabel.text = "Default text"
        
        btn.setTitle("Push to next VC", for: [])
        
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.pushButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
    }
    
    @objc func pushButtonTapped(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        let vc = DetailViewController()
        vc.delegate = self
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
    func callback(_ val: String) {
        theLabel.text = val
    }

}

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    
    weak var delegate: CallBackDelegate?
    
    let textField = UITextField()
    let btn = UIButton()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(btn)
        view.addSubview(textField)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            textField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            textField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            textField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            btn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
        ])
        
        textField.backgroundColor = .yellow
        textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        btn.backgroundColor = .blue
        
        textField.placeholder = "Edit me"
        
        btn.setTitle("Pop back to previous VC", for: [])
        
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.popButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
    }
    
    @objc func popButtonTapped(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        if let s = textField.text {
            delegate?.callback(s)
        }
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this looks precisely like what I've done in my question. I was able to fix it by using the property observer (and protocol/delegate)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem that you are updating the UILabel value anyhow

```
var myClass: MyClass? {
    didSet {
       self.commentLabel.text = myClass?.comment
    }
}
```

You have to update the label text itself, right now it's constant with the first load data